# Shouldn't the biju be allowed free if Naruto really wants to help them?

Tags: naruto

The tailed beasts are forced to serve shinobi, and in the four tails talk with Naruto, they obviously hate doing it. Son Goku asks Naruto what he would do, and he says he would want them to be partners with their jinchuuriku like bee and the hachibi. My question is, if Naruto really wants the solution best for the biju, shouldn't they be allowed to exist outside of the jinchuuriki? Even partnering with jinchuuriki is implying that the beasts cannot be trusted to themselves, which is a shinobi quality kurama hates. Granted, they will probably be used and may even run a rampage, but part of the deal is to get them to be "kinder," like the gyuuki now. In such a case, the humane thing is to ensure that they are "tamed" and then to let them be free, not restricted to a jinchuuriki, even if they are friends with that jinchuuriki.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be a Jinchuuriki to befriend a Bijuu. According to Naruto, he wants to partner up with all the Bijuu, even though not all of them are sealed inside of him.

He can't really change his situation with Kurama since extracting Kurama from him will mean the he would die, however Naruto means that Shinobi and Bijuu can be allies/friends like Shinobi and other Shinobi.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that require all nations to be cooperative and friendly and not send shinobi to go after and capture the tailed beasts?

It would be possible after the Great War, but certainly wouldn't be likely since people fear these beasts. (From a realistic perspective)